# Connecting to DashDB with WAMP and PHP 7 on Windows

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have a website built with Zend Framework, ran by Wamp32 and PHP 7 on Windows 10, connected to a MySQL database.

I am now trying to add a connection to DashDB.

I have downloaded the PECL files [from here](https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2/1.9.9/windows), installed them in the ext directory of PHP 7, added them to the **php.ini** file, and I can see both **php_ibm_db2** and **php_pdo_ibm** in the extensions menu of WAMP.

In my **global.php** file, I have the following:

```
$database = "BLUDB";
$user = "dashdb_user";
$password = "dashdb_passwd";
$hostname = "dashdb_host";
$port = 50000;

return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=mysql_db;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
        'adapters'=>array(
            'db2' => array(
                'driver'         => 'IbmDb2',
                'database' => "DRIVER = { IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER }; DATABASE = $database; HOSTNAME=$hostname; PORT = $port; PROTOCOL = TCPIP ; UID = $user ; PWD = $password;",
            ),
        )
    ),
```

I also added the credentials to DashDB in the **local.php** file

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        // for primary db adapter that called
        // by $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
        'username' => 'mysql_username',
        'password' => mysql_passwd',

        // to allow other adapter to be called by
        // $sm->get('db1') based on the adapters config.
        'adapters' => array(
            'db2' => array(
                'username' => 'dashdb_user',
                'password' => 'dashdb_passwd',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Finally in the **Module.php** file, I have that:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $sm->get('db2');
}
```

But when I try to load the website, this error occurs:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException: The ibm_db2 extension is required by this driver. in F:\wamp\www\playdon_website\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 1130
( ! ) Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An abstract factory could not create an instance of db2(alias: db2). in F:\wamp\www\playdon_website\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 1130
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0303  357304  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.5798  867056  Zend\Mvc\Application::init( )   ...\index.php:17
3   3.4846  3664936 Zend\Mvc\Application->bootstrap( )  ...\Application.php:281
4   3.8506  4129480 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent( ) ...\Application.php:169
5   3.8506  4129480 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners( ) ...\EventManager.php:251
6   4.3917  4660464 call_user_func:{F:\wamp\www\playdon_website\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php:490} ( )    ...\EventManager.php:490
7   4.3917  4660464 Application\Module->onBootstrap( )  ...\EventManager.php:490
8   4.4072  4670080 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( )  ...\Module.php:33
9   4.4073  4670600 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create( )   ...\ServiceManager.php:530
10  4.4073  4670600 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( ) ...\ServiceManager.php:597
11  4.4073  4670600 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromAbstractFactory( )
```

Comment: Are you running PHP on Windows or Bluemix? Your question is tagged as Bluemix but I am wondering if you are running your PHP locally and connecting to the dashDB service in Bluemix only.

Comment: My PHP is running locally, on a Windows 10 OS.

Comment: Maybe the Bluemix tag is wrong here?

Comment: I added the dashdb tag, are you running the dashdb from Bluemix? anyway I don't think it will matter here, but definitely the ibm-bluemix tag was confusing initially.  Your question looks like related to dashDB only.

Comment: Obviously, you need the DB2 driver, as the error message indicates.

Comment: Obviously I do. But as stated, they are installed...

Comment: Judging by the error message, Zend thinks otherwise for some reason. Do you have the [IBM Data Server CLI or Runtime Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217) set up?

Comment: I finally decided to run the server on Linux. On this platform, drivers are well received by Zend